# How can detect user allow to open application with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a jnlp file that I want to open with Javascript as follows in the user's browser:

```
document.location = 'jnlp:https://www.gl.com/test.jnlp'
```

The browser will show a pop-up to the user to ask permission to open this link.
like this:

[image]

I want to know when the user has clicked the Open Link button by JavaScript.